# nodejs: how to best coordinate sessions and sockets

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

Background:

We have a working web app that uses sockets (socket.io) to connect several clients to a single server.

On the server there is an object that is essentially a list of the connections.  When the client first connects it sends basic information and the server stores it like so:

```
connections[socket.id] = { "name": name, "id": id, etc. };
```

Having the list of connections organized by socket ID allows for easy disconnection handling with notifications to other clients, etc., and this simple design worked great for basic testing and lightweight use.  However, moving forward to real use outside of a closed network it will of course be necessary to maintain proper user accounts and require users to sign in and be authenticated.

Question:

We're using express (and fairly new at it), so there are numerous examples of session/cookie use to get a session going and restrict access to certain pages depending on req.session.user.  No problems getting some basic stuff in place there.  But at this point I'm unclear if there's a good ("standard" design pattern) way to tie that session information into the socket.  For example, in our closed-world app the user enters their username in a simple alert dialog and it gets passed to the server right when the socket gets created, which allows for populating the connections[] entry above.

But now the username/pw is entered on a login page before the (restricted) app page is actually loaded, and we would like to use the session-authenticated username, for example, to populate the socket data (above) that will get created for that user.  Hope this makes sense.

I can imagine some ways to go about this, but they seem inelegant at best, cumbersome and error-prone at worst.  It seems like there should be a common design pattern to fit this situation.  I've searched here without success so far, can anyone enlighten please?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/b3n0n/aenima is a kind of unobtrusive frame with auth php side using google api and socket runing for realtime support, beside you dont need to handle later nodejs errors due to static content handling, node is for speed, you need it light as a feather ;)